# Еquation of the height in triangle

Tags: geometry, vectors, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

My task is to find the equation of the height in triangle ABC given the coordinates of the three points. The coordinates of the points are: $A(1, 2), B(-2, 1), C(-1, -2)$.
The solution that I wrote is:
СН is perpendicular to AB. AB has coordinates (-3, -1). It follows that the equation is -3x -1y + C = 0.
Point C (-1, -2) lies on the line. $$ 3*(-1) -1 * (-2) + C = 0$$ $$C = -5$$
The equation of CH is: $$-3x -1y -5=0$$
My question is, is this solution to the problem correct?

Comment: Your equation should be $-3x-1y-5=0$. Without the $=0$ it's not an equation.

Answer (score 1):

You have neglected the first rule with such questions:

> DRAW THE FIGURE!

If you would have done that, you would have realised that you are dealing with a right-angled triangle, which means that two of the sides are heights of the triangle.

This being said, your solution is right, as you can see from this drawing:

[image]